# AsyncTask or Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am implementing an Android application where I make use of some API calls using `HttpResponse,HttpClient` etc to obtain the response. Given below :

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(targetURL); 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

In one case I want to call the API when the Back button is pressed. It goes to another Activity when the Back button is pressed.

Should I call the API in the `onBackPressed()` method ?

Should I call the API in a new Thread in the `onBackPressed()` method?

Should I use `AsyncTask` to call the API? If Yes then which method?

What would be the best approach?

Comment: **"Should I call the API in the onBackPressed() method ?"** : No. There aren't many occasions where you should be intercepting the BACK button and when you do you shouldn't be performing complex tasks such as network operations. The BACK button is designed to terminate the current `Activity` and return to either a previous `Activity` or to the home screen. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Squonk I just want to make the API call(It will make some changes on the server) and the call should be made when the Back button is pressed

Comment: The only safe (and easy) way I can think of is to do this using an `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

 new ViewItems().execute();

 }

 public class ViewItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Loading..",
                "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(targetURL); 
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
 String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        return 0;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

progressDialog.dismiss();

 // then your next activity code

    }

     }
```

Comment: Putting the code in doInBackground() will ensure that it is called only when the Back button is pressed?

Comment: yes it will be called only when back key is pressed.. For disable multiple time back key press, do so some condition inside OnBackpressed()

Comment: @KarthickPandiyan : Intercepting the BACK button and preventing the user from leaving the current `Activity` is bad Android design and breaks the normal Android UX.

Comment: @Squonk yes off-course its bad practicing, but if have the requirement mean we have to crack that rule na.. and we may call finish() in OnPostExe() right

Comment: @KarthickPandiyan : Breaking the rules isn't a good solution - finding a way to do it without breaking the rules is better. Also from your comment "we may call finish() in OnPostExe() right" - what if the network operation takes some time to complete? The user will be locked into the `Activity` thinking their device has stopped or simply won't be able to do anything else.

Comment: @KarthickPandiyan This solution didnt work. The API wasnt called on pressing Back.

Answer (score 0):

see this code , (via AsyncTask)

```
public class getHTTP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]); 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        return responseBody;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

1:

```
doInBackground :  this is main method , when you execute getHTTP class for get URL, The main task this method.
```

2:

```
<String, Void, String> : these is return values and Parameter Values of doInBackground
```

3:

```
onPreExecute : this method run before doInBackground (show alertdialog please wait)
```

4:

```
onPostExecute : this method running after doInBackground , in this method you want parse responseBody and hide alertdialog please wait.
```

how to used getHTTP?

```
new getHTTP().execute("http://example.ex");
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to the problem.

I called the API in a new `Thread` in the `OnBackPressed()` method.

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    //API call here
            }
        }).start();
}
```